# JavaFX jump character

Tags: javafx

Im new to javaFX and im trying to build a little game.
Im trying to get my character to jump using this method:

```
 private void Jump(ImageView iv){
            TranslateTransition tt = new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(0.6),iv);
            tt.setAutoReverse(true);
            tt.setCycleCount(2);
            tt.setByY(-200);
            tt.play();
```

here Im calling this method:

```
app.setOnKeyPressed(new javafx.event.EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
                public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                    if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.UP) {
                        Jump(mainC);
                    }
```

The proplem I'm trying to solve is that the "user" is able to call the "Jump" method while the character is in the air.

I want the character to come back from the jumping to its original layoutY.
Or to disable the Jump method while the character is in the air.

I tried to use an if statment that unable calling the method only when getLayoutY
is what i want it to be, for some reason it did not work:

```
private void Jump(ImageView iv){
        if(iv.getLayoutY() == 400.0){
            TranslateTransition tt = new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(0.6),iv);
            tt.setAutoReverse(true);
            tt.setCycleCount(2);
            tt.setByY(-200);
            tt.play();
        }else {

        }
```

Thank you.

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: .. and stick to java naming conventions!

Comment: Im new to programing and to this site. so please explain yourself..

Comment: a) read the referenced help page b) learn the naming conventions